# How to remove Rows that have English (or a specific languages) sentences in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a pandas data frame which has 2 columns, first contains Arabic sentences and the second one contain labels (1,0)

I want to remove all rows that contain English sentences.

Any suggestions?

Here is an example, I want to remove the second row

> إيطاليا لتسريع القرارات اللجوء المهاجرين، الترحيل [0]
>
> Border Patrol Agents Recover 44 Migrants from Stash House [0]
>
> الديمقراطيون مواجهة الانتخابات رفض عقد اجتماعات تاون هول  [0]
>
> شاهد لايف: احتفال ترامب "اجعل أمريكا عظيمة مرة أخرى" - بريتبارت   [0]
>
> المغني البريطاني إم آي إيه: إدارة ترامب مليئة بـ "كذابون باثولوجي"    [0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of common English letters and remove a line which contain either of these letters, like this:

```
ENGletters = ['a', 'o', 'i']
df = df[~df['text_col'].str.contains('|'.join(ENGletters))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list of English words and detect when a word is used.

```
letters = 'hello how a thing person'.split(' ')
def lookForLetters(text):
    text = text.split(' ')
    for i in letters:
        if i.lower() in text:
            return(True)
    return(False)

print(lookForLetters("المغني البريطاني إم آي إيه: إدارة ترامب مليئة بـ "كذابون باثولوجي"))
print(lookForLetters("Hello sir! How are you doing?"))
```

The first print line will return False and the second print line will return True.
Be sure to add more common English words to the first list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use langdetect to filter your df.

from langdetect import detect

```
Df['language'] = df['title'].apply(detect)
```

Then filter you df to remove non arabic titles.

```
df = df[df['language']=='ar']
```